# Tensorflow, how to utilize tf.equals as a boolean?

Tags: python, lambda, tensorflow

So I've googled this subject for the past while and haven't come across any working solution.

So I have a lambda function here that (I want to / hope should) iterate over a list ("iterateOverMe") and replaces all elements equal to the value specified ("value") with "1". Any other value should be marked with "9".

```
idk = tf.map_fn(lambda x: 1 if tf.equal(tf.cast(x, tf.int32), value) else 9, iterateOverMe, dtype=tf.int32)
```

But I get the error message saying the following:
    *"TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the value of a tensor."*

It, however, is giving the expected True/False values when I directly print out the tf.equal statement at least!

**Things I've tried.**

1: use reduce_all on the tensors, didn't work, I am still getting the same error.

TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the value of a tensor.

2: use the suggested "if t is not None", which did not work because it's seemingly never equal to None no matter what.

So I get a list of 1's like this, which is sadly wrong.

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

3:  Tried using tf.cond like so. But because I want to return true or false that doesn't work at all. Needs to have callables.
    idk = tf.map_fn(lambda x: 1 if tf.cond(tf.equal(tf.cast(x, tf.int32), iterator), True, False) else -1, modifiedTrainingLabels, dtype=tf.int32)

4: This ... this abomination also didn't work.

```
idk = tf.map_fn(lambda x: 1 if tf.cond(tf.equal(tf.cast(x, tf.int32), iterator), lambda : True, lambda: False) else 9, modifiedTrainingLabels, dtype=tf.int32)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the [`tf.where()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where) operation, which evaluates a condition at multiple locations in a tensor in parallel; and the [`tf.fill()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/fill) operation, which generates tensors of a given shape.

Let's say you have a `tf.Tensor` of 10 values, called `iterateOverMe` and a goal value called `value`:

```
iterateOverMe = ...                                       # shape: (10,)

mask = tf.equal(tf.cast(iterateOverMe, tf.int32), value)  # shape: (10,)

result = tf.where(mask,
                  tf.fill(tf.shape(iterateOverMe), 1),    # If `mask` is true.
                  tf.fill(tf.shape(iterateOverMe), 9)     # If `mask` is false.
                 )                                        # shape: (10,)
```